# Springboot homepage after login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I just want to display the homepage and the users name after login but I keep getting a 404 not found error.

here is the index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 th:action="@{/index}">Hello<h1 th: th:text="${name}"></h1> </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    @GetMapping("/sign-in")
    String signIn() {

        return "sign-in";
    }

    @GetMapping("/sign-up")
    String signUpPage(User user) {

        return "sign-up";
    }


    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    String signUp(User user) {

        userService.signUpUser(user);

        return "redirect:/sign-in";
    }

    @GetMapping("/sign-up/confirm")
    String confirmMail(@RequestParam("token") String token) {

        Optional<ConfirmationToken> optionalConfirmationToken = confirmationTokenService.findConfirmationTokenByToken(token);

        optionalConfirmationToken.ifPresent(userService::confirmUser);

        return "redirect:/sign-in";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String welcome(User user, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("Name", user.getName());

        return "index";
    }
```

I've been trying this for a while now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The websecurity config is configured so that the default succesuful URL is index.html

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to access "localhost:9090/index". It looks like you have mapped the "/index" endpoint to your index.html page.

Comment: May your component scanning missing, can you show your project package structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the request mapping to

`@RequestMapping(value = {"/index", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Also, try calling localhost:9090/index (without the .html) as Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana said.